# join two tables based on partial string matching

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have two tables where i save the count of some tables on haddop hive.
Table1 columns: date, table, count (whre table name is in lower case)

```
01/07/2018 base1.tablename1 300
01/07/2018 base1.tablename2 100 ...
```

My second table has the same shape: date, table, count (where table name is in upper cases

```
02/07/2018 TABLENAME1 200
02/07/2018 TABLENAME2 10
```

I would like to have a new table

`Tablename_T1 tablename_T2 CountT1 CountT2 DateT1 DateT2
TABLENAME1      tablename1  300       200   01/07/18 02/07/2018
TABLENAME2      tablename2  100       0    01/07/18 02/07/2018`

I tried this query but it is not working

`select *
from count_tables a, count_tables2 b
where a.tablenamelike concat('%',b.tablename,'%')`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the a.nom_table has predictable order then we can write like

```
select *
from count_tables a, count_tables2 b
where substr(a.nom_table,7,length(a.nom_table))=lower(b.nom_table)
```

Comment: it does not work.
The second table has capital letters in the column nom_table

Comment: I edited my query as per your requirements. Can you kindly try it.

Comment: Why you meant by it does not work. Is it syntax error?

Comment: The syntax is correct. the ouptout is  Done. 0 results.

Comment: I truelly don't undrestand where the issue is

Answer (score 1):

Using `instr()` function

```
select *
  from count_tables  a
       inner join count_tables2 b on a.datet1=b.datet2
 where instr(a.tablename,b.tablename) > 0
```

Add dates to the join condition `on a.datet1=b.datet2` if you do not want duplication of each date from table `a` by each date from table `b`.

Also it is possible to use `locate(string substr, string str[, int pos])` function:

```
where locate(b.tablename, a.tablename) > 0
```

Comment: I would like to know if it is possible to change the query on join of the date.
table 1 on date1 and table2 on datet2-1day ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: @Dora  Sure. use `date_sub(b.date2, 1)`

Comment: Sorry I have this error 
"FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableStringObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector"

Comment: @Dora Provide your query please. Exception says that you are using string in place of boolean. Wrong where statement probably

Comment: This query works but does not give me day-3 days 
"select  *
  from  table1 a
       inner join table2 b
 where a.nom_table=lower(b.nom_table)
 and a.`date`> date_sub(b.`date`, 3);"

Comment: @Dora Select date and date-3 without join and you will see does it work correctly or not